# Curve overlapping faces

Tags: bezier-curves

Trying to create something like image one. I've used a curve to make the basic shape. Question is what I should do with the overlapping geometry inside. Is it a manual fix (which would probably render this unfeasible given how many bends I need) or should I be treating this differently? I did look at self collisions with physics but this seems a little long winded and doesn't get an exact result. Or maybe it doesn't even need fixing?

As usual, still learning and just trying to find the right way to do things. Thanks all[image]

Comment: Please don't repost the same questions. Wait for an answer on the one you posted first.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: I got an answer on the first question in the form of two links but it didn't answer the question, so I've tried to be more specific

Comment: In that case just edit the original post and be more specific on that post itself. Creating a new post just causes a mess for everyone. There is a edit button right under where you have written the question.